# Detailed text overlay for a Stacked Bar Chart {vegabrite} in R

Tags: r, vegabrite

I would like to replicate [Vega-Altair Stacked Bar Chart with Text Overlay](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/stacked_bar_chart_with_text.html) using [vegabrite](https://vegawidget.github.io/vegabrite/) package in R.

[image]

My **vegabrite** script (below), however, shows only the total amount per "variety" field.

```
library(vegabrite)

bars = vl_chart(width = 300) %>%
  vl_add_data(url = "https://vega.github.io/vega-editor/app/data/barley.json") %>%
  vl_encode_x(field = "yield", type = "quantitative", aggregate = "sum") %>%
  vl_encode_y("variety:N") %>%
  vl_mark_bar()%>%
  vl_encode_color('site:N')

text = vl_chart(width = 300) %>%
  vl_add_data(url = "https://vega.github.io/vega-editor/app/data/barley.json") %>%
  vl_encode_x(field = "yield", type = "quantitative", aggregate = "sum") %>%
  vl_encode_y("variety:N") %>%
  vl_mark_text(dx = -15, dy = 3) %>%
  vl_encode_text(field = "yield", type = "quantitative", aggregate = "sum", format = ".1f") %>%
  vl_encode_color(value = 'white')

bars + text
```

[image]

Is there a way to add text as per "site"? It seems the above **Altair** code has set `detail='site:N'`, but I could not find any relevant option in vegabrite documentation.